# How to use the logarithm method to solve $18^{4x-3}=(54\sqrt{2})^{3x-4}$ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> What value will satisfy this equation: $$18^{4x-3}=(54\sqrt{2})^{3x-4}$$

Please use the logarithm method. I am having a problem in expressing $54\sqrt{2}$ in the power of $18$. My book simply says that it is $18^{3/2}$. But I can't understand how.

Comment: Have you tried taking the logarithm of both sides?

Comment: $18=9*2$ which means the square root would be $3\sqrt2$ right? Hint: $54 = 9*6 = (9*2)*3$

Comment: and with these two comments, the problem becomes easier.

Comment: I tried again but I am getting (4x-3)/(3x-4)=(log9*sqrt(2))/(log3sqrt(2))

Comment: It's still possible to get a solution even if you don't notice that.  It will just be a lot messier.  Take the logarithm of both sides to get an equation with 2 messy linear equations.

Comment: @user166748 Considering that there are over 1800 questions about logarithms on the site, a title should be more specific than "A logarithm problem"

Comment: @900sit-upsaday It has been edited (not-by-me).

Comment: @AhaanRungta I know. (I edited the title). The comment was for the future.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Ah makes sense, good point! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @900sit-upsaday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$54\sqrt2=18*3\sqrt2 = 18 *\sqrt18 = 18^\frac{3}{2}$ as the square root is also the positive one half exponent which can added if the terms of multiplied.

Thus, your problem could be rewritten as $4x-3=\frac{3(3x-4)}{2}$ which could be rewritten as $8x-6=9x-12$ which is fairly easy to solve.

Answer (score 3):

1. *Hint #1*: Take the logarithm of both sides. Think about what base you might want to use.
2. *Hint #2*: Write $ 54 \sqrt {2} $ in terms of $18$.
3. *Hint #3*: Let $ 18^x = y $. Rewrite in terms of $y$.

Comment: How write 54sqrt(2) in terms of 18

Comment: $ 54\sqrt{2} = 18 \cdot 3\sqrt{2} = 18 \cdot \sqrt {18} = 18^{\tfrac{3}{2}} $ @user166748

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** First,
$$
\begin{align}
18^{3/2}
&=18\sqrt{18}\\
&=18\cdot3\sqrt2\\
&=54\sqrt2\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $\log(54\sqrt2)=\frac32\log(18)$.

Next, take the log of both sides of your equation and use $(1)$.